# What does this regex mean in django?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'm learning django from a book and I've got into advanced urls, in here there is a regex that it's not explained:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<page_slug>\w+)-(?P<page_id>\w+)/',
        include([
        url(r'^history/$', views.history),
        url(r'^edit/$', views.edit),
        url(r'^discuss/$', views.discuss),
        url(r'^permissions/$', views.permissions),
    ])),
]
```

I understand that it's about removing redundancy, but how does it actually work?
Where do you get `page_slug` and `page_id` from and what's with the - between them?

Comment: In [docs(link)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) it's pretty much explained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are moving onto advanced urls I presume you understand how the basic url markup works.
The regex patterns are used whenever we are dealing with variable url patterns for e.g. In case of a blog, urls might read as

- `domain.com/post-1/`
- `domain.com/post-2/`

or

- `domain.com/shortpost-1/`
- `domain.com/shortpost-2/`

and so on.

We can see a common pattern here which can be related to as a page slug( or prefix) and page/post id.
So we create two variables namely page_slug and page_id. (Note: The variable names like anywhere else can be renamed to your liking.
The regex is hence created as `/(?P<page_slug>\w+)-(?P<page_id>\w+))/'`
where:

- **`?P<>`** : defines that we are defining a variable
- <**`text`**> : text is your variable's name
- **`\w+`** : is your regex which defines what pattern is acceptable (In this case \w represents anything in the set `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` and `+` represents any number of repititions . If you want to learn more on this I'll refer https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html for reference and http://regexr.com/ for practise.
- and the **`-`** in between is simply a compulsary text which could have been replaced with say **`-no-`** to look like **`domain.com/page-no-1/`**

The rest of the markup is similar to normal urls which means that any url begining in the given pattern **`(?P<page_slug>\w+)-(?P<page_id>\w+)/`** followed by the suffix is handeled by the mentioned view.

e.g. - `domain.com/post-1/history/` - is handeled by `views.history` and so on.

The important part now is how do these variable names affect your views. 
If you are using function based views, your history view will be defined as :

```
def history(request, page_slug, page_id):
        #Your code using the two variables received.
        #These might be values stored in db to dynamically fetch values
```

In class based views to access the url parameters you use `self.args` or `self.kwargs` so you would access it by doing **`self.kwargs['page_slug']`**

Comment: Great explained, understood everything, by the way, in this example i have to add page_slug and page_id to every fuction is that right?

Comment: how to use/call these 2 parameters(i.e. page_slug, page_id) from html template? like this:`<a hred="{ % url 'myapp.page' thepage - thepage_id %}" `?

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the following urls:

```
/abc-def/history/ (abc goes to page_slug and def to page_id)
/ghi-jkl/edit/
```

etc